# Как подключить подключить клиент-серверную БД к среде разработки в MAMP на macOS?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, macos, localhost, mamp

Есть база в phpMyAdmin. Хочу подключить клиент-серверную БД к среде разработки. Но как это сделать? Недавно пересел на macOS и тут нет open server, только некий MAMP который я не понимаю. Единственное что есть, при запуске локального сервера на сайте MAMP есть пример подключения, который ниже. А подключать пробовал при помощи кода еще ниже. Вот только моя база не подключается. Первое `echo` выводит - Вы подключились к MySQL, а вот информации о подключении к базе нет.

Файл php_error.log говорит следующее:
thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/connect1.php on line 3
[27-Sep-2017 20:07:20 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/connect1.php:3
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/connect1.php on line 3

```
$user = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$db = 'inventory';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306;

$link = mysqli_init();
$success = mysqli_real_connect(
$link, 
$host, 
$user, 
$password, 
$db,
$port
);

    echo "<p>Вы подключились к MySQL!</p>";
mysql_select_db($db)
or die("<p>Ошибка при выборе базы данных имя_вашей_базы_данных: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
echo "<p>Вы подключены к MySQL с использованием базы данных {$db} .</p>";
```

Comment: может быть проще было ошибку загуглить? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579099/fatal-error-uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы мешаете **Mysql_** и **Mysqli_**. Это не одно и тоже.
Первый убрали из **PHP 7+**.

А ошибка говорит, что **Mysql_** у вас нет.
Если у вас версия PHP ниже 7 то его можно/нужно просто установить.

Но сильно не советую. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php